# c# textbox value in 2 forms

Tags: c#

in c# i created 2 forms, of which on form 1, i placed a texbox "t1" and i need the value placed that textbox to appear in a textbox on form2.

Answer (score 1):

Well that would depend on what you are doing with the information in the first form.  If you are saving the information you can always access it again and populate the textbox of the second form on page load (I am, of course, assuming that you have these forms on separate pages).  If they are on the same page, you can write code that populates that field once the first box has lost focus (or something like that).

Answer (score 1):

Since only 1 form can have focus at a time, I don't see the point. You could have an event handler that handles events for form1, but since the other form wouldn't have focus then it will never be called.

Probably you just want to initialize the text in the other textbox to be the same as the text in the first one when it is loaded. This can be done easily enough in the load method: (sorry this is VB but should be easy enough to translate)

Public Class Form2

```
Private Sub Form2_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)  _
```

Handles MyBase.Load

```
    TextBox1.Text = Form1.TextBox1.Text

End Sub
```

End Class

Answer (score 0):

If it's a one-way dependency, then the second form should register an event handler for text change events on the first form; and the content of the handler would be `form2.textbox.Text = form1.textbox.Text`

For a two-way dependency, make sure that you check the values for equality before doing the assignment (otherwise you will end up in an infinite loop).